# Getting the UTC timestamp

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone, utc

An [old Stack Overflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683) suggests that the way to get the UTC timestamp in Java is the following:

```
Instant.now()   // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

Unfortunately, this does not work for me.  I have a very simple program (reproduced below) which demonstrates different behaviour.

**On Windows**: the time is the local time and it is labelled with the offset with GMT

**On Linux**: the time is again the local time, and it is labelled correctly for the local timezone

---

**Question:** How do we display the UTC timestamp in a Java program?

---

My sample source code is as follows:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Date;

public class UTCTimeDisplayer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.name"));
        Date currentUtcTime = Date.from(Instant.now());
        System.out.println("Current UTC time is " + currentUtcTime);
    }
}
```

**Windows Output:**

```
C:\tmp>java UTCTimeDisplayer
Windows 10
Current UTC time is Fri Jan 22 14:28:59 GMT-06:00 2021
```

**Linux Output:**

```
/tmp> java UTCTimeDisplayer
Linux
Current UTC time is Fri Jan 22 14:31:10 MST 2021
```

Comment: what happens when you do `System.out.println(Instant.now().toString())`?

Comment: @Eugene it gives the same output.

Comment: There is something fishy... `MST` is `GMT-7` (`UTC-7`), not `GMT-6`.

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is `System.out.println(Instant.now().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC))`

Comment: Or maybe you want this? `System.out.println(Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")));`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TimeZone problem …](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812700/timezone-problem-in-java). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107898/simpledateformat-returns-wrong-time-zone-during-parse), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47307909/dateformat-parse-not-return-date-in-utc), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59671609/simpledateformat-with-timezone-displaying-dates-in-my-timezone-how-do-i-fix-thi) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52475409/getting-the-current-time-millis-from-device-and-converting-it-into-a-new-date-wi)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code:

```
Date.from(Instant.now())
```

You are mixing the terrible legacy classes with their replacement, the modern *java.time* classes.

Don’t.

Never use `Date`. Certainly no need to mix with `java.time.Instant`.

To explain your particular example, understand that among the `Date` class’ many poor design choices is the anti-feature of its **`Date#toString` method implicitly applying the JVM’s current default time zone** while generating its text.

You ran your code on two different JVMs that had different current default time zones. So you got different outputs.

Sun, Oracle, and the JCP gave up on the legacy date-time classes. So should we all. I recommend you not spend time trying understand `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and such.

You asked:

> Question: How do we display the UTC timestamp in a Java program?

```
Instant.now().toString()
```

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/B8CDdY).

> 2021-01-22T21:50:18.887335Z

You said:

> On Windows: …
>
> On Linux: …

You’ll get the same consistent results from `Instant.now().toString()` across Windows, Linux, BSD, macOS, iOS, Android, AIX, and so on.

---

Here is a table I made to guide you in transitioning from the legacy classes.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The `java.util.Date` object is not a real date-time object like the [modern date-time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` (or UTC). When you print an object of `java.util.Date`, its `toString` method returns the date-time in the JVM's timezone, calculated from this milliseconds value. If you need to print the date-time in a different timezone, you will need to set the timezone to `SimpleDateFormat` and obtain the formatted string from it.

I would suggest you simply use `Instant.now()` which you can convert to other *java.time* type.

The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

However, if you still want to use `java.util.Date`, use `SimpleDateFormat` as mentioned above.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date currentUtcTime = Date.from(Instant.now());
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
        System.out.println("Current UTC time is " + sdf.format(currentUtcTime));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Current UTC time is 2021-01-22 21:53:07 UTC
```

Answer (score 3):

> suggests that the way to get the UTC timestamp in Java is the following:

> `Instant.now()   // Capture the current moment in UTC.`

This, and most answers in this thread, are **misleading**.

Instant represents an instant in time. It's 'solarflares' time: Absolutely not one iota about it represents anything that is invented by human brains, and UTC is a timezone: A human invention. The cosmos, the sun, astronomy - they have no idea what UTC is, and don't care - and that's what Instant is all about. Instants are devoid of such human concepts as 'hours' or 'days' or 'timezones'. It makes no sense to ask an instant what day it happened on. It cannot tell you; some event occurred: If I ask a russian from the 19th century when that happened, they'll likely give a completely different answer vs. if I ask someone living a mere 100 miles west, for example. Instant doesn't know which localization to apply and thus doesn't let you ask it this question - that's a good thing, objects should not expose methods to which any answer it gives is either gobbledygook or at least requires knowing about all sorts of surprising caveats.

Crucially, if you tell me '... in UTC', you surely can tell with exacting detail which month, which day, etcetera. **And Instant does not do this**, which is why it is misleading to say that a `java.time.Instant` represents a moment of time in UTC. **It doesn't. It represents a moment in time (not in any particular timezone).**

Yeah, internally Instant, just like Date, is just a light wrapper around what `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns: "millis since epoch", but the crucial thing to understand about it, is that 'UTC' is not part of what it *means*, and therefore, when you give an Instant instance to some other method (such as System.out.println, to a database via JDBC, etc), that method is under absolutely no obligation to assume that UTC is semantically relevant.

When you want to mix human notions of time keeping (years, days, months, hours, minutes, milliseconds, and, yeah, timezones) with the notion of a more or less absolute* time, the right answer is `java.time.ZonedDateTime`. Note that any representation of time in something that isn't `java.time.*` based is by definition broken, as it is in most programming languages - turns out time is a lot more complex than most takes on a library to represent it realize. The fact that `java.time` is in effect the 4th attempt at writing a time library should be ample indication that it's hard to get it right.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

*THAT* is what you want - that isn't just implementation-detail-wise what you want, but it is code that exactly describes what you **mean**: Right now, at the UTC time zone, stored in an object that semantically doesn't just store the right time but also stores, and tightly entangles into its very identity, that it is specifically in UTC and is not to be re-interpreted, moved to the local zone, or any other such shenanigans - at least, not unless you explicitly ask it to do so.

> `Date currentUtcTime = Date.from(Instant.now());`

Note that Date is the old API and therefore necessarily broken. In this case, Date is a lying liar who lies - it doesn't represent a date, it represents an instant; it is badly named. (The second API is Calendar, also broken. For example, that is also a lying liar who lies: It doesn't represent a Calendar whatsoever. It represents some bizarre amalgamation of a zoned datetime and an instant and is fit to represent neither as a consequence). Any time you go to the Date API weirdness ensues, and something as simple as 'I just want the concept of the time, at some specific moment, in UTC' isn't possible in these APIs. You are now dependent on barely defined behaviour of all the various libraries up and down the chain - you're effectively stuck praying that they do the right thing, or delving into exotic settings to try to cajole these libraries into doing what you want.

TL;DR: Use `java.time`.

*) Note that ZonedDateTime is **not** absolute. For example, if you have the time `January 20th, 2023, 8 in the morning, at Europe/Amsterdam`, in the form of a `ZonedDateTime` object, then the amount of seconds that will pass between now and that moment sure seems like it does not change and will not change when e.g. amsterdam goes through an hour change due daylight savings. However, if the dutch government decrees that henceforth The Netherlands will no longer move the clocks at all and will stay in summer time forever (which is **likely** - EU directive is already in place, it's now just a matter of when), then at the moment the gavel lands, your appointment shifts by 1 hour exactly.

That hopefully provides crucial insight in the difference: Instant, representing events (hence why I like to call it 'solarflares time', to disentangle it from human time keeping concepts as much as possible), doesn't even understand the very concept of such a decision having an effect on things. ZonedDateTime on the other hand is inherently bound up in it - hence the `Zone` in `ZonedDateTime`.

If you want to store barber appointments and use `Instant` to do it, you *WILL* be an hour late or early sooner rather than later.

Comment: Nice comprehensive discussion. My understanding is that UTC does unfortunately intrude because instant is measured relative to the Unix epoch, and while the epoch isn't tied to UTC or any timezone or calendar or any human naming, it is just a point in time, the fact is that it can only be described in commonly understood human terms and as such it needs a date label and a location for that label so midnight 1Jan 1970 UTC is as good as any other but it the most sensible chosen way to describe it.

Comment: Though I think you said the same in your paragraph starting 'Yeah, internally ...'

Answer (score 2):

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) object and also a [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object by themselves
only contain a point in time, but no timezone information.
Furthermore, the [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--) method of the `Date` class
implicitly chooses the timezone provided by the system environment,
which is not what you want.

Therefore you need to chose the timezone (in your case UTC) explicitly.
For example like this:

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println("Current UTC time is " + offsetDateTime);
```

This will (independently from the operation system) print

```
Current UTC time is 2021-01-22T22:37:21.950354100Z
```

where the trailing `Z` denotes the zero timezone offset (i.e. UTC).

Answer (score 2):

A simple method that could work!

My requirement was date time with milliseconds

`2021-11-25 19:55:00.743`

```
private String getUTCTimestamp() {
        ZonedDateTime utc = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        return utc.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instant.now()  is essentially the period of time since the epoch, (midnight 1 January 1970 in UTC), but you are using a Date to present that instant. Date is a reflection of the instant with millisecond precision, but as explained in the documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html, presenting a date should be done using a Calendar, as the presentation of a Date depends on the host. Essentially Date wraps the instant but is displayed according to other factors.

The simplest approach now if you want to output the instant is to use OffsetDateTime so that you can elect to present the instant in your desired timezone - UTC in your case. Use either `OffsetDateTime.now()` or `OffsetDateTime.ofInstant()` but if you are using the instant within your application logic then just stick with Instant.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your program has to work with older java versions, so here is an example for 1.5:

```
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat tfGMT = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    java.util.Calendar cUTC = java.util.Calendar.getInstance (java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone ("GMT+0"));
    tfGMT.setCalendar (cUTC);
    java.util.Date d= new java.util.Date ();
    String s= tfGMT.format (d);
    System.out.printf ("now=%s [unix ts=%d.%03d]\n", s, d.getTime()/1000, d.getTime()%1000);
```

Mind you, the first three lines don't have to be repeat at every call, but keep in mind that `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread-safe. (Simple solution: create one for each thread.)

Example usage (it shows that setting `TZ` doesn't affect UTC-timestamp):

```
$ TZ=GMT+3 java5 now_utc; TZ=GMT-3 java5 now_utc
now=2021-01-24 12:56:14 [unix ts=1611492974.264]
now=2021-01-24 12:56:14 [unix ts=1611492974.726]
```

Comment: For Java 1.5 I would suggest (1) upgrading to a newer java version (2) if changing Java version is out of the question on the short sight, use Joda-Time for date and time work.

Comment: Yes, those are very good suggestions. Also you can just use the solution I've written which works without upgrading or using external component.